# How to convert a SXW file into a RML file through openerp_sxw2rml.py?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, rml, swx

I am trying to convert a SXW file into a RML file, using **openerp_sxw2rml.py**, but it is giving too errors and it is generating an empty RML file. I am sure that the content of the SXW is right, because I am using existing SXW files from the OpenERP modules, to check if they are being transformed in a right way.

I copied the **account_balance.sxw** from the **account** module, for example, and pasted it into **openerp_sxw2rml** folder to test it. Then I executed this:

```
sudo ./openerp_sxw2rml.py /opt/openerp7/addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml/account_balance.sxw > /opt/openerp7/addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml/account_balance.rml
```

And the result is the next:

```
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 30: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 
OpenERP SXW2RML - The OpenERP's report engine

OpenERP SXW2RML is part of the OpenERP Report Project.
OpenERP Report is a module that allows you to render high quality PDF document
from an OpenOffice template (.sxw) and any relationl database.
: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 31: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: __version__: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 34: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 35: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 36: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 37: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 38: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
from: can't read /var/mail/reportlab.lib.units
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 40: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 41: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: import: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 43: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: class: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 44: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: General DOM API utilities.: not found
./openerp_sxw2rml.py: 45: ./openerp_sxw2rml.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why is this happening? Has anybody had the same problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it using python

```
sudo python openerp_sxw2rml.py /opt/openerp7/addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml/account_balance.sxw > /opt/openerp7/addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml/account_balance.rml
```

(You have to specify **python** instead of **./** )

Answer (score 3):

First go to `addons/base_report_designer/openerp_sxw2rml` path and follow below command

General syntax

```
python openerp_sxw2rml.py src_path_of_sxw > dest_path_of_rml
```

Where `scr_path_of_sxw` is a source path of your *.sxw file* is store and `dest_path_of_rml` is a destination path where *.rml file* is store.

Comment: Thank you Odedra! Your answer was right too, but I think that sajadkk answered earlier. I voted yours like an useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following pull request fixes the issue: https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra/pull/52

Sincerely,

Malte

Comment: So the problem was that there was not a shebang, thank you for the information!